# Calling a javascript function after a server call in asp.net web forms

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is there a way in web forms to call a javasctipt function after making a server call for example

```
function showAlert(){ 
   alert("hello");
}


 <asp:Button ID="callJavasctips" runat="server" Text="callJavasctipt" OnClick="callJavaSctipt_click" />
```

In MVC I can say OnSuccess = "showAlert()" is there a way to do this in webforms?

**UPDATE**

I ended up using ScriptManager instead of Page.ClientScript because it didn't work with update panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the callJavaSctipt_click event in the code behind, do the following:

```
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("MyScript","<SCRIPT Language='JavaScript'> alert('Hello'); </SCRIPT>");
```

Comment: `Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` is obsolete. see msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock.aspx

Comment: @crocaduck81. The difference between RegisterClientScriptBlock and RegisterStartupScript is that RegisterStartupScript adds the script to the top of the aspx page where as RegisterClientScriptBlock adds the script to the end. The choice is important if you are accessing any html controls from the script. In this scenario it doesn't matter which ever you call.

Comment: @Bala R. Obsolete in the .NET 4.0 framework. But it could be used with  framework earlier than that.

Comment: it's marked obsolete in .net 4 but it has been deprecated since  .net 2.0, I think.

Answer (score 1):

For calling javascript after, you'll have to use [`ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) on your button's click handler.

I'm not sure if you would be interested in this, but you can define onclientclick="some_javascript_snippet" for `<asp:Button />` but it's called before the server side handler.